# Why is my line of code giving the wrong character location in a string

Tags: r, string

I am working with a dataset where the data my variables column is in the format `blah blah [text I actually want]`. I have wrote a line to try to replace every data point in the variables column with a new data point with just `text I actually want`.

I thought I finally cracked it, but it does not seem to actually be working so far.

```
melted$variable = str_sub(
    melted$variable, start = gregexpr(
        pattern ="\\[",melted$variable)[1], end = (
            str_length(melted$variable) - 1
        )
    )
```

`melted` is my data set, and `variable` is the column name

Comment: Thank you for the edits! I never know how to space it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `base R`, we can do

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("(?<=\\[)[^]]+", x, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "ex1" "ex2"
```

#### data

```
x <- c("blah blah [ex1]", "blah blah [ex2]")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` and extract everything between `[` and `]`

```
sub(".*\\[(.*)\\].*", "\\1", x)
#[1] "ex1" "ex2"
```

Or using `str_extract`

```
stringr::str_extract(x, "(?<=\\[).*(?=\\])")
#[1] "ex1" "ex2"
```

where `x` is

```
x <- c("blah blah [ex1]", "blah blah [ex2]")
```

which can be replaced with `melted$variable`.

Comment: @bensir: do note that thanks is expressed by upvoting and/or marking the question as anwser.